Set language for Open Liberty logs running with Maven plugin
I have a Jakarta EE project based on Maven and use the openliberty-runtime plugin to be able to directly start the application in dev mode.
It works, but the log messages are German, since that is my personal locale. But I want to have the logs in English. How can I set that?
I found so far, that a JVM option should be used and -Duser.language=en-US could be set. But it is not clear where exactly that should be done. I tried a jvm.options file and I tried the jvmOptions attribute in plugin's configuration, but no luck.
Other solutions on SO describe how to do it in an installed Open Liberty, but I want to have it when running as mvnw liberty:dev.

I am not sure if you are talking about the messages.log that the Liberty server generates or info that is printed to the terminal from the Liberty Maven plugin? Either way, much of what you see in the terminal when running the plugin in dev mode comes directly from the messages.log. The plugin simply mirrors the information from the log. There are some additional messages from the plugin itself.
Are you seeing a mix of German and English right now when you run dev mode? I think you would need to configure Liberty to use English in addition to specifying the locale on the mvnw command.

@CherylKing Yes, I am referring to the output when running liberty:dev, which comes from Open Liberty when starting and deploying. And yes, I see both English and German, but the Deployment Messages are English. Problem is, how should I config Liberty, when I use it via the Plugin. There is no installed Liberty to config something, so it must be possible in the pom.xml.

If you are trying to change the locale used for the Liberty messages.log (which also gets printed to the console when running in dev mode) to English, you can add a jvm.options file in the src/main/liberty/config folder with the following contents.
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.country=US

This worked for me when I specified fr for the language and CA for the country even though my default locale was en and US.

Hey nice, that did the job, thanks! I was almost there, but probably had the wrong entry in jvm.options. Interestingly though, there are still some little parts here and there which are German, but most messages are fine now.
